# Why Does Traversal Source g Stop Working?

Tags: docker-container, janusgraph, tinkerpop3, java-17, gremlin-server

## Problem

Why does their example problem stop working after a day-or-two?

Deleting and recreating the JanusGraph-Docker-container fixes the problem.
Nothing has been changed since this execution was run, as seen below.
Why does this Gremlin-Server connection throw-up an error on `ResponseException`?

## Reproduction

### Steps

1. Create-and-Startup [JanusGraph [Docker-container]](https://docs.janusgraph.org/getting-started/installation/) 
   `docker run -d -p 8182:8182 janusgraph/janusgraph`
2. Run Java-Project (Day-A)
3. Wait indeterminate timeframe
4. Run Java-Project (Day-B)
5. Results

   1. Expected: Java-Project would run like always
   2. Actually: Java-Project has runtime error 
      `The traversal source [g] for alias [g] is not configured on the server.`

### Logs

```json
2023-05-04 07:32:59,332 [INFO] [c.j.m.Manifests.gremlin-driver-loop-2] ::    0 attributes loaded from 97 stream(s) in 20ms, 57 saved, 1788 ignored: []
2023-05-04 07:32:59,408 [INFO] [o.a.t.g.d.Connection.gremlin-driver-conn-scheduler-2] ::     Created new connection for ws://localhost:8182/gremlin
2023-05-04 07:32:59,408 [INFO] [o.a.t.g.d.Connection.gremlin-driver-conn-scheduler-1] ::     Created new connection for ws://localhost:8182/gremlin
2023-05-04 07:32:59,408 [INFO] [o.a.t.g.d.ConnectionPool.gremlin-driver-host-scheduler-1] ::     Opening connection pool on Host{address=localhost/127.0.0.1:8182, hostUri=ws://localhost:8182/gremlin} with core size of 2
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: The traversal source [g] for alias [g] is not configured on the server.
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportJoin(CompletableFuture.java:413)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.join(CompletableFuture.java:2118)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet.one(ResultSet.java:123)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.hasNext(ResultSet.java:175)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.next(ResultSet.java:182)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.next(ResultSet.java:169)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal$TraverserIterator.next(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:115)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal$TraverserIterator.next(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:100)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteTraversal.nextTraverser(DriverRemoteTraversal.java:92)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.traversal.step.map.RemoteStep.processNextStart(RemoteStep.java:80)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:135)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.AbstractStep.next(AbstractStep.java:40)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.DefaultTraversal.next(DefaultTraversal.java:249)
    at Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: The traversal source [g] for alias [g] is not configured on the server.
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler.channelRead0(Handler.java:245)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler.channelRead0(Handler.java:200)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinSaslAuthenticationHandler.channelRead0(Handler.java:126)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Handler$GremlinSaslAuthenticationHandler.channelRead0(Handler.java:68)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.Utf8FrameValidator.channelRead(Utf8FrameValidator.java:89)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

### Code

```
│   pom.xml
│
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │       Main.java
│   │   │
│   │   └───resources
│   │       │   log4j2.xml
│   │       │
│   │       ├───conf
│   │       │       remote-graph.properties
│   │       │       remote-objects.yaml
```

#### `Main.java`

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Transaction;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex;

import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;

public class Main {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote("conf/remote-graph.properties");
        Transaction tx = g.tx();
        tx.open();
        g.V().drop();
//        tx.commit();
//        tx = g.tx();
        Vertex v1 = g.addV("person").property("name","marko").next();
        Vertex v2 = g.addV("person").property("name","stephen").next();
        g.V(v1).addE("knows").to(v2).property("weight",0.75).iterate();
        tx.commit();
        logger.info("g.V().count().next():\t" + g.V().count().next());
        g.close();
    }
}
```

#### `remote-graph.properties`

```
gremlin.remote.remoteConnectionClass=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteConnection
gremlin.remote.driver.clusterFile=src/main/resources/conf/remote-objects.yaml
gremlin.remote.driver.sourceName=g
```

#### `remote-objects.yaml`

```yaml
hosts: [localhost]
port: 8182
serializer: {
  className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1,
  config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }
}
```

#### `pom.xml`

```xml
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>gremlin-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.4-20230429-020227.dc3f877</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: I think you are confusing client-side and "database side" configuration files. The JanusGraph configuration file will look like the one found at `conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml`. That file is part of the JanusGraph distribution. If you have not already done so, you may also want to consider joining the dedicated JanusGraph channel where a lot of JanusGraph experts tend to hang out. There is a link to that channel from https://twitter.com/JanusGraph/status/1537738373896478722

Comment: Thanks to [today's tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76203371/janusgraph-propertykey-is-not-a-user-defined-key) from [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162698/rob), I'm now fixing my mistakes with which [images should be uploaded for questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76203371/janusgraph-propertykey-is-not-a-user-defined-key).

Comment: I know this is a beginner question. I'm not claiming to be an expert. Please allow me to walk in the graph-database gates.